# Use of REST with scaffolding actions

Tags: grails

I see that Grails 2.3 is using REST for the CRUD actions in scaffolding. While it's a great way to learn how REST works, I am wondering if using REST to communicate inside of a single application stack is very efficient. Doesn't it send the request all the way up to the network layer and back down again instead of going directly from the app server to the database? I am visualizing a "pop fly" as opposed to a "line drive." Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: The REST methods exposed are intended for use by other clients, not internally by the same Grails app (server side). So you could call them from the browser client via AJAX or from another app (e.g. a client only webapp)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you say, "using REST for the CRUD actions in scaffolding" you are referring to the basic scaffolding (i.e. `generate-all example.Book`).  The scaffolded controllers are not calling the REST API (`https://yourapp/book.json`) to retrieve the data, they are still using GORM to access the database, and then using the `Respond` method to render the data in the appropriate format based on the Request's content-type (XML, JSON, HTML). So,

### Typical request-response cycle

1. Client, typically an HTML page, makes request (GET `http://yourapp/books/1`)
2. Grails 'parses' request params (`id: 1`)
3. Grails' GORM retrieves data from database and creates object instance
4. Grails resolves response content type to HTML
5. Grails "responds" to the request with an HTML response using a view from the views directory

### SPA/API call

1. Client, typically javascript, makes request (GET `http://yourapp/books/1.json` **)
2. Grails 'parses' request params (`id: 1`)
3. Grails' GORM retrieves data from database and creates object instance
4. Grails resolves response content type to JSON
5. Grails "responds" to the request with an JSON response
6. Client consumes the JSON response and acts accordingly

** content-type can be specified in a number of ways, just used the .json suffix since it is the most transparent.  See http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation.

And to answer your question regarding whether it "very efficient".  I would argue that it is almost always yes, because your payload tends to be much smaller, since you are only transferring data, not data + formatting (HTML, javascript, css, etc).  It also provides a way of separating concerns, allowing the client to focus on state and presentation and the backend to focus on data.  Furthermore, it means that you can create multiple clients (mobile, desktop-based, web-based) using the same backend API.